# How can I use command line arguments in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to run this code using command line arguments where I have a "check.yaml" file using their key and values

```
  {

   "Source" : [foo.c,foo1.c,foo2.c],
                                                                            
   "Test1" : [ ex.c,ex1.c,ex2.x,ex3.c],
                                                                            
    "Test2" : [ ex.c,ex1.c,ex2.c,ex3.c,ex4.c],
   "variant1" : true,
   "varinat2":false
  }
```

I am running this "check.ymal" file using python file "Test.py" and I am getting the
output accordingly:

```py
             
import sys
import yaml
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.parse_args()


with open('hardcode_list.yaml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)

 

with open('test.yaml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)


with open('test.yaml', 'r') as kh:
    yaml_data = yaml.load(kh, Loader=yaml.SafeLoader)
    data_keys = yaml_data.keys()
    if "variant1" in yaml_data_keys and yaml_data["src_14"]:
        del yaml_data['Test2'][4]
        with open('variant1.yaml','w') as K:
            yaml.dump(yaml_data,K)

    elif "variant2" in yaml_data_keys and yaml_data["src_36"]:
        with open('variant2.yaml', 'w') as K:
            yaml.dump(yaml_data, K)

    else:
        print("no variant found")
```

In my project there are 2 variants i.e. variant1 and variant2,here I want to use this 2 variants using command line arguments so that **I dont have set the variables true and false in yaml file** like **variant1:true** **variant2:false**, instead it should come by command line like **python Test.py variant1**.
I am newbie in python trying to learn can you please help me in this, Thanks in advance.

Comment: simple solution: [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv), more comprehensive solution: [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: @matszwecja They're using `argparse`.

Comment: You need to specify all the arguments before calling `parser.parse_args()`

Comment: yeah I am trying doing that, but still not able to find,